# c# application interface is loading slow

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, resources

I'm creating a interface for a application at the moment. Background are all 1x1 pixel. In design time the interface is super slow (visual studio 2012). Moving components is super laggy. If I run the application it takes about 10 seconds for the interface to load.

Some parts of the interface can be hidden. Ones they become visible again they take time to build up / load part by part.

How can I improve this and make the interface much smoother / loading faster?

[image]

**Source code:**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MapTool : Form
    {
        public int Pin_Berekenen = 0;
        public int pin_Settings = 0;

        public MapTool()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BlackSetupUI();
            panel_Berekenen.Visible = false;
            panel_settings.Visible = false;

        }

        void BlackSetupUI()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
            pictureBox_RouteBerekenen.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            panel_Berekenen.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox_settings.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button_pin_berekenen.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            button_Berekenen.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            label_berekening1.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            label_berekening1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            label_Berekening2.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            label_Berekening2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            label_verschil.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            label_verschil.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button_pin_settings.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            label_RouterBerekenen.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            label_Settings.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            pictureBox_settings.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            pictureBox_RouteBerekenen.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            pictureBox_innectis.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
            label_innectis.Parent = pictureBox_bar;
        }

        void WhiteSetupUI()
        {


        }



        private void MapTool_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Pin_Berekenen == 0)
            {
                panel_Berekenen.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            if (pin_Settings == 0)
            {
                panel_settings.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void button_pin_berekenen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Pin_Berekenen)
            {
                case 0:
                    Pin_Berekenen = 1;
                    button_pin_berekenen.Image = Properties.Resources.Pinned;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Pin_Berekenen = 0;
                    button_pin_berekenen.Image = Properties.Resources.Pin;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void button_pin_settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (pin_Settings)
            {
                case 0:
                    pin_Settings = 1;
                    button_pin_settings.Image = Properties.Resources.Pinned;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    pin_Settings = 0;
                    button_pin_settings.Image = Properties.Resources.Pin;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox_settings_MouseHover_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel_settings.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox_RouteBerekenen_MouseHover_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel_Berekenen.Visible = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm just designing the interface there is no data loaded with in this application as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what exactly is your interface "doing". But here are some general tips:

- You can *preload* something while showing splash screen (with or without progress) and then doing all time consuming work (to example, constructing all forms, parsing all configurations, caching graphics, etc). Or even put main application into dll and making exe-file small with the only splash screen.
- You can optimize parent/child controls redrawing and layout operations (`BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` and such), so you don't waste time by calling unnecessary draw operation until it's a right time for it to happens. You can use double buffering, WS_EX_COMPOSITED.
- If you have to much calculations, then perhaps something has to be *virtualized* (you display "fast placeholders" and after caculation replace them with real data) or *cached*.
- You can use one of many tricks to simulate faster (as user can feel) operation: show a small part of data on screen, while prepare a much bigger portion of data in the memory (sort of virtual window), add some intelligent conclusions and caching (if user is moving left, then perhaps he want to continue that way, preload more data from left or, if user is moved right by 100 pixels, perhaps he will want to return, so don't unload that data yet).
- Perhaps you have to much data what you have to profile it and optimize or even use C++ to write speed demanded parts in separate dll's.
- Or maybe you should redesign your UI, split common parts into control, put nested things into user controls, etc, etc..

Comment: The strange part is that if the panel on the left is hidden and then comes visible again its loading component for component. I have edited my question to provide the source code.

Comment: To clarify, when you show hidden Panel, you are not doing anything apart from showing standard components? There are no custom controls what falls into an update loop (when changing visibility and/or layouting)? And this *show* takes a while. Or perhaps UI is slowed down because of the use of `Transparent` color (try to show opaque interface, is it faster) ? Perhaps you are doing something what you shouldn't in the design time. I wouldn't recommend using VS form editor as WYSIWYG, rather split UI into parts, edit them separately and only combine during run-time.

Comment: As you can see in my code nothing is looping just .visible = true.. Ill try to change the some ui parts and tell you the result.

Comment: I changed the static image from google maps to a dynamic html page of google and change the transparent elements to solid. It works much better now. But what is the problem with transparent elements?

Comment: Transparent color is the "slowest" one. To draw transparent color control has to first draw everything below him, then draw own content. Coupled with resizing/moving and some layouts (`TableLayoutPanel` and similair) it can cause some serious UI lag. Especially in designer. There are also dozens of tricks of how to make things working, to example, when rezing/moving stop using transparent color or even replace actual control with the placeholder (opaque panel) and only redraw everything once - at the end of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Hide all of them then when it is fully loaded, show it up

If you want to show animation, you can use Bunifu UI (paid)